# A Plugin to view PDF document in iOS cordova based application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, cordova-plugins, cordova-3.8.0

Can please suggest a working plugin to view PDF in iOS Cordova based application.

```
  I have tried many of PDF related plugins:

  https://github.com/siegfriedbolz/cordova-plugin-file-opener2.git 
  https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/PDFViewer
   but of no use..My application stopped at loading.

 Lastly with I have tried with pebois/phonegap-plugin-PDFViewer:


  I have installed using : 
   "cordova plugin add com.lesfrancschatons.cordova.plugins.pdfreader" 


  In index.html:

  function onDeviceReady() 
        {

            PDFViewer.open("file://sample.pdf","sample.pdf", function (msg) {
                           console.log(msg);//
                           });
      }


//error on pdfviewer.open method
```

- Can any one tell me what is the issue in above method.
- And how can we provide the path for sample.pdf (Hope I am giving any wrong path)
- Or if any PDF plugins for iOS Cordova

Comment: how are you getting the pdf file in ios?

Comment: Via server we are downloading PDF files backend on user request

Comment: As I have above issue I m using direct link to load within the app : $('#scheduleTimingsRender').attr('onclick', "navigator.app.loadUrl('" + pdfLink + "', { openExternal:true });");

Comment: do one thing : use "<div class="pdfcontainer">
  <object data="" >Object can't be rendered</object>
 </div> " and add your pdf path into data tag inside the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use a "homemade" plugin made by me; it get the PDF on a specific URL by a single **GET**.

### PDFUtilities.m

```
#import "PDFUtilities.h"


@interface PDFUtilities()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController;

@end


@implementation PDFUtilities

- (void)viewPdf:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{   
    if (command.arguments[0] == (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR] callbackId:command.callbackId];
        return;
    }

    NSString *url = command.arguments[0];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,(unsigned long)NULL), ^(void)
    {
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDF.pdf"]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
        {
           NSLog(@"pdf downloaded, opening...");

           NSData *pdf = data;

           CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)pdf);
           CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

           if (document == nil) {
               // error
           }
           else 
           {
               NSURL *localURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];

               [pdf writeToFile:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

                self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:localURL];
               [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
               [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:NO];

           }

           CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
           CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
        }]; 
    });

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK] callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (UIViewController*) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return  [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
}
```

### PDFUtilities.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface PDFUtilities : CDVPlugin <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>

- (void)viewPdf:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Remember to add in your **config.xml**

```
<feature name="PDFUtilities">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PDFUtilities" />
</feature>
```

You can call the plugin method on your **Javascript** file just like this:

```
cordova.exec(
            function(){},
            function(){},
            'PDFUtilities',
            'viewPdf',
            [urlpdf]
);
```

Comment: my pleasure, I know what it means get in trouble with Cordova ;)

Comment: Does the PDF viewer has a search search feature? can it open a local file and remote  file?